Jack Henry DMZ: Unable to create account via AcctAdd jXchange service
I'm facing an issue when trying to use AcctAdd jXchange service in DMZ environment for any provider. Every time I try to hit that service, it fails (HTTP 500) with following error message:
<FaultRecInfoArray>
    <FaultMsgRec>
        <ErrCode>200</ErrCode>
        <ErrCat>Error</ErrCat>
        <ErrDesc>The element 'DepInfoRec' in namespace 'http://jackhenry.com/jxchange/TPG/2008' has invalid child element 'ProdCode' in namespace 'http://jackhenry.com/jxchange/TPG/2008'. List of possible elements expected: 'TellerSICCode, SalesPerson, SvcPrvdInfo, Ver_1' in namespace 'http://jackhenry.com/jxchange/TPG/2008'.</ErrDesc>
    </FaultMsgRec>
</FaultRecInfoArray>

I tried removing the field DepAdd.DepInfoRec.ProdCode from XML payload, but I get an error stating that field has an invalid value:
<FaultRecInfoArray>
    <FaultMsgRec>
        <ErrCode>100004</ErrCode>
        <ErrCat>Error</ErrCat>
        <ErrDesc>Invalid service charge code</ErrDesc>
        <ErrElem>DepAdd.DepInfoRec.ProdCode</ErrElem>
        <ErrLoc>DDACCTADD</ErrLoc>
    </FaultMsgRec>
</FaultRecInfoArray>

It was working without any issue a couple of weeks ago, but now I get the same error every time I try to use that jXchange service.
Has anything changed on that DMZ environment?
I used to use following XML data and it was working a couple of weeks ago:
<AcctAdd xmlns="http://jackhenry.com/jxchange/TPG/2008">
    <MsgRqHdr>
        <jXchangeHdr>
            <JxVer></JxVer>
            <AuditUsrId>AuditUsrId</AuditUsrId>
            <AuditWsId>AuditWsId</AuditWsId>
            <AuthenUsrId/>
            <ConsumerName/>
            <ConsumerProd/>
            <Ver_1/>
            <jXLogTrackingId />
            <Ver_2/>
            <InstRtId>102100552 </InstRtId>
            <InstEnv>TEST</InstEnv>
            <Ver_3/>
            <BusCorrelId />
            <Ver_4/>
            <WorkflowCorrelId/>
            <Ver_5/>
            <ValidConsmName>[REDACTED]</ValidConsmName>
            <ValidConsmProd>[REDACTED]</ValidConsmProd>
        </jXchangeHdr>
        <Ver_1/>
        <Ver_2/>
        <Ver_3/>
    </MsgRqHdr>
    <AccountId Rstr="">
        <AcctId JHANull="" MaskVal="" Rstr="">*****</AcctId>
        <AcctType JHANull="" Rstr="">D</AcctType>
        <Ver_1/>
    </AccountId>
    <DepAdd>
        <DepInfoRec>
            <BrCode>2</BrCode>
            <OffCode>ad7922</OffCode>
            <ProdCode>TS</ProdCode>
            <AcctClsfCode>I</AcctClsfCode>
            <SerChgWav>Chg</SerChgWav>
            <SigVerifyCode>N</SigVerifyCode>
            <CustId>[REDACTED]</CustId>
        </DepInfoRec>
        <DepAcctInfo>
            <ClubPln/>
            <ChkGuar>N</ChkGuar>
            <ATMCard>N</ATMCard>
            <ClsOnZeroBal>N</ClsOnZeroBal>
            <HighVolAcctCode>N</HighVolAcctCode>
            <LstPostAcctCode>N</LstPostAcctCode>
        </DepAcctInfo>
        <DepNSFODInfo>
            <ChgODCode>C</ChgODCode>
            <AllowReDepCode>N</AllowReDepCode>
            <ReDepNotCode>N</ReDepNotCode>
        </DepNSFODInfo>
        <DepStmtInfo>
            <StmtCycle>31</StmtCycle>
            <SerChgCycle>31</SerChgCycle>
            <IntCycle>31</IntCycle>
            <ItmTrunc>NoTrunc</ItmTrunc>
            <ImgPrtChkOrderCode>Y</ImgPrtChkOrderCode>
            <ElecStmtType>Email</ElecStmtType>
        </DepStmtInfo>
    </DepAdd>
    <LnAdd>
        <Ver_1/>
        <Ver_2/>
    </LnAdd>
</AcctAdd>

I have reviewed the TG_DepositMaster.xsd file with schema definition and I have found ProdCode under DepInfoRec_CType complex type, see screenshot below:
DepInfoRec_CType complex type definition
<xsd:complexType name="DepInfoRec_CType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      ...
      ...
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="ProdCode" nillable="true" type="ProdCode_Type" />
      ...
      ...
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>


The normal state for that environment is to have schema validation turned on to encourage good XML development practices. It was inadvertently turned off during an update. Once it was discovered, the validation routines were restored.
Schema validation turned on is the normal state of the environment and will remain. The error message you are receiving is alerting you that you are not following schema and is attempting to provide you with the next expected element per schema.

I updated my question to include the schema defintion for DepInfoRec_CType complex type. It seems the XML I'm using it's following the schema. So, I do not why the jXchange service is complaining about it.
